# Mic not working in Skype in Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, skype, microphone

Both mics (internal and from headset) works perfectly with other software like Meet, Zoom, Team but not with Skype.

I installed Skype from the software store and directly from the Microsoft site.

Used `PulseAudio Volume control` to check if can record the input, and it is ok.
Checked `alsamixer` and looks ok, too.

Cannot use `gstreamer-properties` because is no available in Ubuntu 20.10 (at least, I didn't find how to install it)

Do you have any idea how to solve this issue?

Other sounds and camera, are working fine.

Thanks in advance.